# Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I try to resolve includes undefined, For that, I am using && operator.

```
 isAllChecked = label => {
    const { permission } = this.state;

     false value - I need false value when I get data from API,
     But I got an error that includes undefined. for that, I used && operator
     but I got a true value, I don't need to get true value

      const data = !groupItems.some(
      x => !permission && !permission[label] && !permission[label].includes(x)
    );

    // console.log(true) //true

    const data = !groupItems.some(
      x => !permission[label].includes(x)
    );

   // I got a false value using static data without using && operator

  // data output: false (accepted output- getting using static data, but  I need 
   to get the same value when I get data from API, I got an error includes undefined without using && operator)

    return data;

  };
```

However, If I got data from API, this method is displayed can not read property undefined and when I am going to resolve 'includes' of undefined, I used && operator and I got true value.

```
 Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined.
```

I don't need true value, I need false value for the initially mounted component.

my question is that how can I resolve Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined by using && operator or anything.
Here is my code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-a-60764570-3982562-v1-um18k

Comment: does it still not working ?? seem codesandbox is working

Comment: yeah, it works when I used static data , but when I used API , The method doesn't work because includes undefined.

Comment: for resolve I used && operator , but I got a true value .However using static data , I got false value .

Comment: is it a thrid party API?

Comment: can u add api call in sandbox?  cant reproduce error case.

Comment: @AbdullahAbid this is not third party api

Comment: @sujon try it like `data !==undefined && data !==null && <Fragment>Code here </Fragment>`

Comment: I need to get false value . can you update this method instead of array.includes

Comment: @AbdullahAbid wait a second

Comment: ur case is wrong !permission && !permission[label]  can throw error. coz not defined

Comment: try this. i think it is working
const data = groupItems.every(
      x => permission && permission[label] && permission[label].includes(x)
    );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of some, you can use every to check all.

```
isAllChecked = label => {
    const { permission } = this.state;
    const data = groupItems.every(
      x => permission && permission[label] && permission[label].includes(x)
    );
    return data;
  };
```

Comment: when I click on checkbox my output should be this format

{permission:{group:["1","2"]}}
and also if I click second one my output should be this format

{permission:{group:["1","2"]},topgroup:["1"]}. 
currently , I see two default objects like this by using intital state

{permission:{group:[]},topgroup:[]}.
I don't need to get initial state like this {permission:{group:[]},topgroup:[]}. I just want to add data when user click on checkbox.

how can I remove initial state ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60790181/how-to-remove-initial-default-objects-in-reactjs