# How to remove initial default objects in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

when I click on checkbox my output should be this format

```
{permission:{group:["1","2"]}}
```

and also if I click second one my output should be this format

```
{permission:{group:["1","2"]},topgroup:["1"]}.
```

currently , I see two default objects like this by using intital state

```
{permission:{group:[]},topgroup:[]}.
```

I don't need to get initial state like this {permission:{group:[]},topgroup:[]}. I just want to add data when user click on checkbox.

how can I remove initial state ?

```
  UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.setDefault(false);
  }

  setDefault = fill => {
    const temp = {};
    group.forEach(x => (temp[x] = fill ? groupItems : []));
    this.setState({ permission: temp });
  };
```

here is my codesanbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-a-60764570-3982562-v1-um18k

Comment: Basically you want all checkboxes to be unchecked on load ?

Comment: yes , when I select checkbox , it will be add

Comment: @Dreamweaver can you give me the solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829455/how-to-filtering-array-of-objects-to-another-array-of-objects-in-javascript/60830268#60830268

Comment: Did you try removing 
const permission = {
    group: ["can_view", "can_update", "Orange"],
    topGroup: ["can_view", "can_update", "Orange"]
  };
const permission = {
    group: [],
    topGroup: []
  }; 
to